# Splitting string from backslash

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to split a string from a backslash

```
a = 'anido_\na.\nSearch'
```

I'm trying to scrape `anido_` from the string but had no luck using

`a.split('\\')`, `a.partition("\\")`.

The string comes from Selenium's

`driver.find_element_by_xpath(elem).text`,

So I don't think there is anyway of scraping the string any other way.

Comment: Share HTML code sample for the same link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to split as

```
a = 'anido_\na.\nSearch'.split('\n')[0]
```

to get `"anido_"` as output